# Screen capture while backgrounded in iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios9, screen-capture

My main question is, since both IOMobileFramebufferGetLayerDefaultSurface and IOSurface no longer work on iOS 9 and needs a private entitlement to grab the surface, besides AirPlay, what other way is there to capture the screen on iOS 9?

I have come across a very interesting class that wasn't actually ever in previous versions of the OS, but if you look at the methods, there's nothing that specifies the settings, video path to save it to, etc. But most importantly, how can I find out if it's even possible to use? Calling startCapture does not give me any indication that it's working or not.

The header can be found [here](https://github.com/CPDigitalDarkroom/iOS9-SpringBoard-Headers/blob/master/System/Library/Frameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/FigScreenCaptureController.h). What other methods are available to record the screen or capture a screenshot in the background in iOS 9? UIGetScreenImage() or _UICreateScreenUIImage() do not seem to work for me.

Comment: I'd recommend editing your question to ask about the issue you're trying to solve rather than "how does this third party framework work".

Comment: @JAL I have already tried _UICreateScreenUIImage(), which seems to return a black screen for me, even within the app itself. Strange...